# iOS app login to LinkedIn and not show request for permissions

Tags: ios, ipad, linkedin-api

I am developing an ios app and trying to allow the user to connect to their LinkedIn account.

I am using the steps found in 
https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/ios-sdk-auth
where I

1. Registered my app with LinkedIn to get the application id.
2. Updated my `info.plist` with the `*li{application id}*` entries for URL Schemes
3. Called `LISDKSessionManager.createSessionWithAuth()` to start the login process.

However, this only opens up the LinkedIn app on my iPad, but does not show me which permission I had requested nor redirect me back to my app.  I am at a loss to if this is the intended behaviour or am I missing a step.

Note that the sampleapp provided by linkedin also does not show me the page with a list of permissions requested or redirect me back to my own app.

Comment: i am also suffering from the same problem. please add answer if you get any clue  thanks

Comment: Same problem here, also using iPad.

Comment: Same thing happens here. Clueless on what to do...

Comment: As an update to my previous comment: Even the example apps have this problem. (I'm still on an iPad).

Comment: Further update, because of the 5 minute edit window: I sent an AdHoc build to some friends with an iPhone, and the problem is confirmed to be specifically "it doesn't work on the iPad", not "it doesn't work at all".

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the LinkedIn app has an iPad-specific bug that prevents it from returning to other apps after `createSessionWithAuth:` is called, even when all credentials are correct.

(I had to wait for the delivery of a physical iPhone to test my hypothesis, as there is no way to log in like this on a simulator).

---

### Update

My answer was with regard to the 1.0.2 sdk, which also had problems with *all* iOS 9 devices. The iOS 9 problems were fixed with the 1.0.4 sdk, but the iPad problems remain.

Comment: Update: this was with the 1.0.2 sdk, which also had problems with all iOS 9 devices. The iOS 9 problems were fixed with the 1.0.4 sdk, but the iPad problems remain.

Comment: I am not getting you... What should I do ?

Comment: I wasn't answering your question, I was updating my own answer to this question. (That said, I don't *think* you're supposed to send around "please help" links like you just did…)

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. For me, it was about setting our bundles right:

On https://www.linkedin.com/developer/apps/xxxxxx/mobile, make sure that your 'iOS Bundle Identifiers' is the same on your app. Plus, click on Update! I just added and 'forgot' to save them.